# A way to verify specific filter contents

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that uses a filter on a few columns of data. One of these columns has 10 different possible values. I want to verify that there is a specific filter in place--that is, not just that `autofiltermode = true`--but to actually check what the value of that filter is. Is there a way to do this in vba?

For example, if I might want to make sure that the user is only looking at `customers`, 1 of the 10 values in my field. So I'm hoping I can say something like `if filtervalue = "customers" then`.

Additionally, I don't want to verify cell data, I'm asking if there's a way to verify a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample code below will check for the criteria selections given the first cell of the range containing the filter, and the index of the column to check.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    'first argument is first cell of headers being filtered
    'second argument is column to check for filter criteria
    Debug.Print GetCriteria(Sheet1.Range("A1"), 3)
End Sub

Function GetCriteria(rng As Range, lngFilterIndex As Long) As String

    Dim strCriteria As String
    Dim objFilter As AutoFilter
    Dim lngCriteriaCount As Long
    Dim lngCounter As Long

    Set objFilter = rng.Parent.AutoFilter

    ' no autofilter
    If objFilter Is Nothing Then
        GetCriteria = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' autofilter but no selection
    If Not objFilter.Filters(lngFilterIndex).On Then
        GetCriteria = ""
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' iterate criteria
    strCriteria = ""
    lngCriteriaCount = objFilter.Filters(lngFilterIndex).Count
    If lngCriteriaCount = 1 Then
        strCriteria = objFilter.Filters(lngFilterIndex).Criteria1
    Else
        For lngCounter = 1 To objFilter.Filters(lngFilterIndex).Count
            strCriteria = strCriteria & objFilter.Filters(lngFilterIndex).Criteria1(lngCounter)
        Next lngCounter
    End If

    GetCriteria = strCriteria

End Function
```